# Override User Agent Stylesheet to make text accessible

Tags: html, css, inline

I am trying to make a simple, standalone page with menus that populate the text box (the one with "Left 1"). The text in the box is way to small on mobile and on desktop computers.

[image]

I am trying to make this text box legible but can't find a way to. I tried adding code to override the User agent but it didn't work - ideally I would want to do this inline.

[image]

Here's an anonymized [codepen](https://codepen.io/fabulousrice/pen/VwNPRZr) because I don't want to share the whole project publicly

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">


<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-ta-mere.css" />
        <title>martians on earts?</title>


<script src="html2canvas-example-master/html2canvas.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">



</script>

</head>

<body>

<div>



</div>
  
  <span style="color:#FFFFFF;"><h1 style="font-family:Metropolis-Thin,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,light;">
  


  
        
        

          <style>
    .button {
        background-color: #ff7676;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
    .button:hover {
        background-color: #7d7d7d;
    }
    
    
            @font-face {
            font-family: Metropolis-Thin;
            src: url(fonts/Metropolis-Thin.otf);
        }

        html,
        body {
            /* height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto; */
            /* pointer-events: none; */
            background-color: black;
            /* margin: 0; */
            font-family: Metropolis-Thin;
            /* overscroll-behavior: contain; */
        }
    
    a:link {
  color: deeppink; 
  background-color: transparent; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: coral;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: wheat;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: darkturquoise;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.override {
    style:font-size: 25px; !important;
}



</style>
            
  
  <table width="800" border="0" align="center">

<tr>
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;"><span style="font-family:Metropolis-Thin,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,light;"><span style="font-size:72px;"><td colspan="2" align="center">bleep bloop<br />
<br />

</td></span></span></span></span>
</tr>


    <tr>

          

    <td align="center">LEFT
    <br/>
  
  
<input type="text" id="leftLabel" value="Left 1" style="font-family:Metropolis-Thin,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,light;" style="font-size:22px;">



<br/>

<select id="leftSelect" style="font-size:22px;">
  <option value="l1" selected>Flow</option>


</select>


  </td>
  
    
    <td align="center">RIGHT
    <br/>




<input type="text" id="rightLabel" value="Right 1" style="font-family:Metropolis-Thin,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,light;" style="font-size:22px;" class="override";>

<br/>

<select id="rightSelect" style="font-size:22px;">
  <option value="r1" selected>Flow</option>


  
</select>



<br/>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td colspan="2" align="center">
<button id="pandabear" class="button" style="h1">BUTTON</button>
</td>
</tr>


</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have 2 style properties in the same tag. This causes the second style tag to be unaccounted for. The code you currently have is: `<input type="text" id="leftLabel" value="Left 1" style="font-family:Metropolis-Thin,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,light;" style="font-size:22px;">`. The second `style=""` is ignored. you can combine them into one by replacing it with `<input type="text" id="leftLabel" value="Left 1" style="font-family:Metropolis-Thin,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,light; font-size:22px;">`. Though it is best practice to have a separate `<style>` tag and add all the custom properties inside there.